# Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise Java Client Error When Creating Assessment

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, recaptcha-enterprise

I am using Java reCAPTCHA client library, the latest version. I keep getting the error message using okhttp3

> com.google.api.gax.rpc: io.gprc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Unable to resolve host recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com

I have tried setting Java and okhttp3 proxy to hostname-> recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com and port-> 443 but no such luck.